# Assigning unique value wrt the groups in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
            'idA': [11,25,11,45,11,25,35],
            'idB': [30,40,45,20,30,40,90]  
         })
```

I want to create a new column includes a unique value with respect to the *idA* and *idB* by each row. In other words, whenever a pair appears in any other place, the value should be exactly the same. But any other pair - including the reverse one - must be different. To overcome this, I thought to apply a made up math function like this:

```
df['NewValue'] = df.min(axis=1)*(df['idA']*10 + 15*df['idB'])

#   idA    idB  NewValue
#   11      30      6160
#   25      40      21250
#   11      45      8635
#   45      20      15000
#   11      30      6160
#   25      40      21250
#   35      90      59500
```

It seems working. But by following this, *NewValue*  can take any number. I desire to have a simple incrementing integer instead. For this example :

```
NewValue = [1,2,3,4,1,2,5]
```

In reality, I have thousands of rows. So I am also seeking for an efficient solution. Any way to handle this?

Comment: what is your expected output then

Comment: @BENY `NewValue = [1,2,3,4,1,2,5]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, you could use `groupby` + `ngroup`:

```
df['NewValue'] = df.groupby(['idA','idB'], sort=False).ngroup().add(1)
```

Output:

```
   idA  idB  NewValue
0   11   30         1
1   25   40         2
2   11   45         3
3   45   20         4
4   11   30         1
5   25   40         2
6   35   90         5
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way using `pd.factorize()`

```
(pd.factorize(df.to_records(index=False))[0]+1).tolist()
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 5]
```